# connect : connection refused in c program at client side

Tags: c, sockets

I am using the following code to connect to the server at a certain port which are provided as command line arguments ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
   int clientSocketFd ;
   char buffer[1024];

 if((clientSocketFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))==-1)
    perror("socket");

//get the server IP address and PORT
bzero(&serverAddr, sizeof serverAddr);
printf("ip address :- %s\n",argv[1]);
inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &(serverAddr.sin_addr));
serverAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_port = atoi(argv[2]);

printf("PORT :- %d\n",serverAddr.sin_port);
//connect to server
if(connect(clientSocketFd,(struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == -1)
    perror("connect");

printf("Connecting to the server %s on port %s \n",argv[1],argv[2]);

while (1)
{
    //receive incoming data
    if(recv(clientSocketFd, buffer,1023, 0)==-1)
    {
    printf("buffer : %s\n" ,buffer);
    printf("Received from Server : %s \n",buffer);
        break;
    }


}
close(clientSocketFd);
```

}

but at the client side , it shows "connect : Connection Refused"...

If I use telnet , then it shows connected , but not able to connect through the above code of client.c
plz help

Also I changed the number of maximum allowed pending connections to 100 , then also the problem did not solved... :( ...help plz

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are connecting to the wrong port. Change:

```
serverAddr.sin_port = atoi(argv[2]);
```

To:

```
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
```

Think of these structures as being used to communicate with another planet where they write their numbers differently. You have to convert to and from the way you write numbers to the way they write numbers, otherwise you get nonsense.

The `htons` function converts ports numbers from the way your computer stores them to the way they are used on the network. The `ntohs` function converts port numbers from the way they are used on the network to the way your computer stores them. Socket addresses are in network byte order.

Comment: Minor clarification: this is needed because ports are stored in [big (aka network) byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) in the address structure.

Comment: @user1726647 Then you should accept the answer, by clicking the check mark icon next to it.

Comment: Sir , one more thing , i use the port number of server as "4099" and when i print it at the client side , it shows "784" ..why does this happen ??

Comment: The code you are using to print it is probably broken. Does it use `ntohs` to convert it to native byte order? (Think of these structures as being used to communicate with another planet where they write their numbers differently. You have to convert to and from the way you write numbers to the way they write numbers, otherwise you get nonsense.)